# Core data save vs merge changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my app, I always delete the whole data inside core data when the app is loading.
The data can be save from several threads or classes.
Therefore I thought about using `mergeChanges` and not `save`.
My question is that, do I really need to use `mergeChanges` and drop `save`?
I don't mind the (2 of 3 core data managed objects) data won't save if the app die.

Comment: This is a bit vague. Which `mergeChanges` are you referring to?

Comment: When I update managed objects, I save them to core data, will it be better using 'mergeChanges' if I don't need the data when app die?

Comment: I still don't know which `mergeChanges` are you referring to?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you will need `save` to propagate changes to the store and be able to access them from newly created `managedObjectContexts` in different threads.